# Let $A\in M_n(\Bbb{C})$ such that $\text{Im}(A)\cap\text{Ker}(A)=\theta$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, matrix-rank

The actual question looks like-
Let $A\in M_n(\Bbb{C})$ such that 
$\text{Im}(A)\cap
 \text{Ker}(A)=\{\theta\}$, where $\text{Im}(A)=\{AX 
\mid X\in\Bbb{C^n}\}$ and $\text{Ker}(A)=\{X\in\Bbb{C}^n\mid AX=\theta$}, then prove that there exists non-singular matrices $P$ and $D$ of orders $n\times n$ and $\text{rank}(A)\times\text{rank}(A)$ respectively such that $$ A=P
 \begin{pmatrix} D & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \\ \end{pmatrix} P^{-1} $$ 
Can anybody suggest me a proper solution to that question? 
Thanks for assistance in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider a basis of $\mathbb{C}^n$ using the decomposition $\mathbb{C}^n = Im(A) \oplus Ker(A)$.